# How to read /dev/ttyS1 (when only write works)

Tags: linux, tty, stty

After a kernel/busybox update my half-duplex /dev/ttyS1 port has become write only.

What works: `echo "Hello ttyS1" > /dev/ttyS1`
What doesn't work: `cat /dev/ttyS1`

Same pattern when I try writing c++ read/write interfaces: write works, read times out.

At this point I suspect a really low level misconfigured setting.

Does anyone know of any stty settings, system security flags, or similar that might be blocking receive on this one port or interfering with half-duplex 2-wire wiring?

Comment: How does your device signal direction change?

Comment: It is an RS-485 connection. Are the direction change protocol settings I should check?